# Create complex JSON Model using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

so I got this JSON:

```
{ "games": [
{
  "location": "germany",
  "team1": {
    "name": "test1",
    "tore": "2"
  },
  "team2": {
    "name": "test2",
    "tore": "3"
  }
},...
```

My Model Class for this JSON looks like that(where I think i got the error)

**MODEL CLASS:**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class GameModel {

    public String location;
    @SerializedName("team1")
    public Team team1;
    @SerializedName("team2")
    public Team team2;


    public String getLocation() {
        return zeitpunkt;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location= location;
    }

class Team
    public String name;
    public String tore;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTore() {
        return tore;
    }

    public void setTore(String tore) {
        this.tore = tore;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Team{" +
                name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", tore='" + tore + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And my GSON looks like that..

**GSON Class**

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("games");

gameModelList = new ArrayList<>();

Gson gson2 = new Gson();
for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
    GameModel inputGame = gson2.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), GameModel.class);    
    gameModelList.add(inputGame);
}
return gameModelList.toString();
```

My location from `games` works that i call in my CustomAdapter Class, but everytime I want to get the name of team1 like

```
GameModel gm = getItem(position);
tvTeamOne.setText("" +gm.team1.getName());
```

I get a `java.null.lang pointer exception`
I also tried the debugger, and it displayed me `team1:null`, so he doesn't get the `String`

logcat:

```
07-04 13:26:53.720 25600-25600/de.xxxxxxx.app.mc.xxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.xxxxx.app.mc.xxxxx.GameAdapter.getView(GameAdapter.java:40)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add you full log cat.

Comment: sorry forgot that, added the log cat now

Comment: Your error is in your `Adapter` (hint in the first line of logcat: `at de.xxxxx.app.mc.xxxxx.GameAdapter.getView(GameAdapter.java:40`) at line 40. Your `View` is null. Please post the relevant code, too. Also, consider to format your question properly, so others are more willing to answer it. And finally, read [What is a NullPointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) ;)

Answer (score 2):

first create models:

```
public class Team1
{
    public String name;
    public String tore;
}

public class Team2
{
    public String name;
    public String tore;
}

public class Game
{
    public String location;
    public Team1 team1;
    public Team2 team2;
}

public class YourRootObject
{
    public List<Game> games;
}
```

then simple parse to object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
    YourRootObject result = (YourRootObject) gson.fromJson(yourJson, YourRootObject.class);
catch(Exception e){}
```

and in result all data if it exists, will be proper parsed and you will get no null in values

Comment: To save the work of writing the models I use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ . Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

All the code here is irrelevant .Only the  "GameAdapter"  getview is required.Also I think since you are calling "getItem(position)"

you need to change this method like this.

```
 public GameModel getItem(int position) {
        return gameModelList.get(position);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In which class should i put this method? cause my GameAdapter looks like this: 
`public class GameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GameModel>{

    public GameAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GameModel> arrayListGames) {
        super(context, R.layout.game_adapter_item, arrayListGames);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.game_adapter_item, null);`
..
TextViews..